# Enable O365 MFA with no old phone number via PowerSehll

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I have create 2 x PowerShell script for enable and disable the MFA, it works, but when i want to remove the phone number , the disable MFA script do no remove the phone number. so when i enable the MFA again for the user. the old number is still there

***Enable MFA***

```
Import-Module MSOnline
    $Username = 'o365admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$Password -ErrorAction Stop
    Connect-MsolService -credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop
    $mfa = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement")
    $mfa.RelyingParty = '*'
    $mfa.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
    $auth = @($mfa)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth"
```

***Disable MFA***

```
Import-Module MSOnline
    $Username = 'o365admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$Password -ErrorAction Stop
    Connect-MsolService -credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop
    $mfa = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement")
    $mfa.RelyingParty = '*'
    $mfa.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
    $auth = @()
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of myself

***This code only disable the MFA but do not remove the phone numbers etc***

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth"
```

***I have to add this as well to remove the phone numbers***

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationMethods $auth"
```

***So the code will looks like:***

```
Import-Module MSOnline
    $Username = 'o365admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$Password -ErrorAction Stop
    Connect-MsolService -credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop
    $mfa = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement")
    $mfa.RelyingParty = '*'
    $mfa.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
    $auth = @()
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationMethods $auth"
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth"
```